# Paypal SetExpressCheckout requires DoExpressCheckout?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I have finished the workflow for SetExpressCheckout but I see 2 other API's: GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment. I don't want to call 2 extra url's - I want direct payment. Is calling SetExpressCheckout sufficient for ordering online transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as far as I know, and recall it, is that SetExpressCheckout is the preparation of the order, and DoExpressCheckoutPayment is the finalization of the transaction.

Nothing stops you from invoking them on the same request in your end though, if you use the server API.

You should maybe look at another API in this case. Maybe DoDirectPayment is what you want?

Comment: I will check out DoDirectPayment

Comment: No, DoDirectPayment is a bad choice. It forces me to make the payment forms on my website. That's what Paypal is for...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, DoExpressCheckoutPayment is required in order to finalize a PayPal Express Checkout transaction.

Express Checkout works as follows:
 1. SetExpressCheckout initiates the transaction and returns a TOKEN
 2. You redirect the buyer to PayPal by appending the TOKEN to a special crafted URL
 3. The buyer reviews and agrees to the purchase
 4. The buyer is returned back to a 'return URL' you initially specified in the SetExpressCheckout API call
 5. Now you can either show a final 'Order review' page (and optionally use the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API call to get back order details), or immediately call the DoExpressCheckoutPayment API call to finalize the transaction.

If you don't call DoExpressCheckoutPayment, you will *not* finalize the transaction. Meaning there will *not* be any money transferred to your account.

Answer (score 3):

From what I recall from the last time I worked with this API, SetExpressCheckout is your chance to set up the payment and make sure everything is valid. This gives an you an opportunity to display an order confirmation page, so the user can confirm order and then the payment is actually charged via DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

You do not have to do them in separate requests. You can immediately DoExpressCheckoutPayment after you SetExpressCheckout if you wish.

Comment: No, you cannot immediately call DoExpressCheckout after SetExpressCheckout because we need the token from SetExpress to navigate to paypal, get the buyerid/payment etc and use it to call DoExpressCheckout.